# Can I see how all views are internally linked in Visual Studio 2012 MVC 4 App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 app in Visual Studio Premium 2012 and would like to see how all of my views are linked together. I believe one of my Views is no longer used (no other Views are linked to it). I would like to delete the View to avoid any confusion in the future. I don't want to delete the View if one of my other Views still links to it however. Is there a way to see how my Views are linked together in my Visual Studio 2012 app?

Back in the day FrontPage had a "Hyperlinks" view that would show how each page of a web site was connected and whether each link was working or broken (see the "Hyperlinks view": http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/frontpage-help/about-views-HP001019753.aspx).

Is there a way to do something similar in Visual Studio? I could search the solution for any ActionLinks to the view but thought it would be quicker if there was a visual way to see an orphaned View.

Comment: If you have views you don't know whether they are used or not, you might have problems in your design specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to just see that it's not being called from anywhere.

Just do a find in files for the action name, wrapped in quotes: "ActionNameYouWantToDelete"

If you haven't reused that exact name elsewhere, that should find all references to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for confirming that there is no way to tell in Visual Studio if it is being called or orphaned.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how MVC works.  Urls go to Controller actions, not Views.  Controller actions return Views.

By default, a Controller action that end with `return View();` will return the View with the same name.

Alternatively, you can specify the view do use with `return View("viewName");`

It should be be relatively easy it see if there is a matching Controller action for a given View.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I feel I should clarify my question. I do have a matching Controller action for the View as I needed to use the View when my project first began. The business requirements have changed since then, however, which has made the View unnecessary. So, I have a Controller action & a View that are most likely dormant/never used. I would like to delete both to clean up my code and reduce any possible confusion in the future. But, I am not 100% sure I have removed all of the old references to the View. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So, the next logical step is to take that action name and controller name and see if you are calling them.

Comment: Hi KennyZ - what would be the most efficient way to do that?